# I'm getting this error on LocationManager in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, location

I'm getting this error "cannot resolve method requestLocationUpdates". I don't know what to do anymore, I already changed "this" into "getActivity" since I'm using fragments.

By the way, this code is working when i tried it from a different project but it's not in a fragment. I tried to do it in a fragment and this is where I get the error.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipients, container, false);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, getActivity());

    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String uri = "http://maps.google.com/?q="+latitude +","+longitude;
            StringBuffer smsBody = new StringBuffer();

            smsBody.append(Uri.parse(uri));
            String msg = (" Hello, Timothy. You are at" + " " + longitude + " " + latitude ).toString();

            try {

                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, smsBody.toString(), null, null);



                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Message Sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        ex.getMessage().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Here are my imports:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using acOutputReport, but specifying a query name.  When you use acOutputReport, you need to provide a report name.  It seems like you want to use acOutputQuery, or create a new report based off the query and then use acOutputReport, "NewReportName".  See [the Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You're using acOutputReport, but specifying a query name. When you use acOutputReport, you need to provide a report name. It seems like you want to use acOutputQuery, or create a new report based off the query and then use acOutputReport, "NewReportName".

Take a look at [Microsoft's page on the OutputTo method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx) for more info.